# Retrieving result from List List<Future<Callable<Integer>>>

Tags: java, multithreading

Task:
You are given a List of Future objects that return Callable. You should execute these Callable objects in the reverse order, starting from the end of the List and return a sum of values returned by these Callable objects.

Method to implement:

import java.util.concurrent.*;

```
class FutureUtils {

    public static int executeCallableObjects(List<Future<Callable<Integer>>> items) {
        // write your code here
    }

}
```

so, the question is how to retrieve the results of Callable tasks correctly

What I understand:

1) In order to submit Callable we need to use

ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
exec.submit(put Callable);

2) In order to retrieve result of Callable execution, we need to use Future object;

I understand how to retrieve results from the Callable list but not from >>

I believe I miss something.

This is the code I wrote trying to understand how to complete the task

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        List<Future<Callable<Integer>>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Future first = executorService.submit(new PrintIfPrimeTask(1));
        list.add(first);

        try {
            ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
            Future<Callable<Integer>> good = list.get(0);
        Callable<Integer> temp = good.get();
       Future<Integer> kek = exec.submit(temp);

      Integer a = (Integer) kek.get();
            System.out.println(a);


        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        executorService.shutdown();

    }
}
```

It gives

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.base/java.util.concurrent.Callable
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:36)
```

PrintIfPrimeTask does nothing but return 2

```
class PrintIfPrimeTask implements Callable<Integer> {
    private final int number;

    public PrintIfPrimeTask(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"In order to submit Callable we need to use ExecutorService"* - no, just `call()` on the `Callable` object, no future involved, you immediately get the result.

Comment: You had a raw usage of `Future` (without `<...>`, and I am not certain with returns Callable, as one submits a `Callable` to the `Future` to wait for its completion on get. Waiting long to get computed some Callable, which is then to be executed, seems artificial. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Comment: Indeed, a `Future<Callable<...>>` looks like a [concurreny Matryoshka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll). If this is the task, one can try to solve it. But as it is written now, you could simply walk over the list and compute the sum as `sum += items.get(i).get().call();`. No `ExecutorService` or whatever. (Of course, this will block if the `Future` objects are not completed, but that's not your problem...). Are there any further details about what the *goal* of this assignment should be?

Comment: @luk2302 Thank for the answer, tested - agree, it works by just using the call();

Still, it does not answer the question of how do I execute a task from the  List<Future<Callable<Integer>>> given list, the Type confuses me as on the one hand we have a Future object, on the other hand, it contains Callable<Integer>. I cannot execute direct object from the list as it's Future Type.

Comment: I think the main point is: You are receiving a list of `Future` objects. *Who* will complete these `Future` objects, and when will this be done? If you receive them, for example, from an `ExecutorService`, then the service will complete them. But again: This point is, strictly speaking, not relevant for solving the assignment (it might only be relevant if you want to solve the assignment in a way that *makes sense*...)

Comment: @Marco13 Thank you for the answer, that worked. No other details were listed in the task. If you are interested it is on https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/4945